# Generating high current negative supplies

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, negative-voltage, power-supply

I'm trying to generate a high current negative supply (30A, -2V). This is to be a negative symmetric supply along with a (30A, +2V) rail, with an actively driven ground which I need to be system ground. This also happens to need to be a programmable supply, but let's set that aside for the moment.

The various methods which I have used to generate negative supplies in the past have been limited to fairly low currents - maybe about 1-1.5A. I've been looking around, and most discussions or solutions seem to talk only about these kind of low currents.

There's also the virtual ground approach, but at these currents I'm not quite convinced that would be the way to go. There's also the nagging problem of floating the load, which I'm not particularly sure I can do.

I've been looking at the [LTM4662EY](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4662f.pdf) for the positive rail, which seems to quite nicely fit my requirements. I'm also looking at the [LM5170](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5170-q1.pdf), which seems a little overkill, but I think the bidirection current bit of the circuit might help get me the negative rail as well.

I'm looking for answers to the following questions :

- What kind of approach is normally used to generate high current bipolar/split supplies?
- Is there something like the LTM4662EY which can generate negative voltages, or some way to get the LTM4662 to generate the negative voltage I want?
- What sort of approach should I be using to get the LM5170 to generate negative voltage output.
- Any other controllers or application notes or pointers that might help, especially if it seems like I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's your input voltage? If it's much more than 2 V, you might not need very high switch current to achieve high output currents if your design involves a transformer.  Do you need regulation on both the positive and negative outputs?

Comment: @ThePhoton The input is a single 24V rail. I can stick a transformer in there, subject to being able to maintain symmetry of the output rails. I do want regulation on both the rails. I expect the load will be more or less symmetric, but I would like to avoid making that assumption. If the outputs can behave as very low impedance fixed voltages (which I can somehow program), I'd prefer that.

Comment: You probably need to look at this as two separate supplies, rather than a bipolar supply. Typical bipolar designs will not regulate one of the two outputs (which is usually only a problem if the regulated output is very weakly loaded). An isolated design (forward or flyback, maybe others I don't know as well) might allow you to use the same design for both + and - outputs, just switching the terminals.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm fine treating it as two separate supplies. What I am seeing is that the vast majority of solutions somewhat readily available are specifically positive supplies. Though yes, if it is an isolated topology I could probably just physically invert the output. While I've stuck linear regulators to ground to generate negative rails, it's not something I've ever done with switching supplies though.

Comment: Have a look at AN19 from Analog (former Linear). I don't know if LT1070 (or LT1170) can quite get you to 60 W, but give your high Vin/Vout ratio I think it might do it.

Comment: Is the load just a single resistor? how many pins in the "load"?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf 3 pins. It's a complex geometry, behaves sort of like a supercap. Ground and + and -

Comment: @ThePhoton This says 5A 10A(max), though for duty cycle of 50%. Is the idea to use this to switch a beefier external MOSFET, or that if the duty cycle is pushed down to 10% it might be able to tolerate 30A, or that a transformer might step down whatever comes  out?

Comment: @ChintalagiriShashank, if you're doing Flyback or Forward, the LT1x7x switch only has to switch the primary current. And since you're stepping down voltage, the transformer can step up the current. (But like I said, I'm not sure it will work out)

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks. I see what you mean. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't think it's a solid answer. There are probably better, more modern, parts out there to do the same job. But if you do the design with LT1070, you'll understand why things are the way they are a lot better.